# "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" when deleting from a very real table in the user's schema

Tags: oracle

I have a table that definitely exists in the logged-in user's schema (therefore I own the table) and is not a view/synonym/anything wacky.

I can select from it, but when I try and either insert, update or delete from this table, I get

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I'm completely baffled.

Comment: Anything in the alert log, like an ORA-600 or -7445?

Comment: I see nothing in the alert log.

Comment: Any trigger on the table?

Comment: No triggers either.

Comment: Sounds like you may not have insert/update/delete permissions on the table in question. Try starting there and let us know what you find.

Comment: @JoeChin *IF* the user really does own the object as stated in the question then this answer can't be correct.

Comment: True, but that is a big if, being able to select from a table doesn't mean the logged in user owns it. This was more to guide the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Once I had a similar Problem. To shorten a rather long story, just flush your shared pool.

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;
```

Somehow Oracle seems to create an corrupted entry in the statement cache. Problem has been resolved after flush. After that, we were unable to reproduce it.

You need some administrative privileges to flush it.

One final **note:** ORA-00942 does not exist in the database documentation at all.

According to my notes, we used this Oracle version.

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: I'm definitely interested to try this if I ever have the problem again. I'm not sure what got it into that state in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

What does the output of

```
SELECT OWNER,OBJECT_TYPE
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = '<OBJECT NAME FROM SELECT STATEMENT>';
```

show (assuming you don't want to give us the object name).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem it was due a bad character
I ran the below request to good name view

```
select '@'||VIEW_NAME||'@' from user_views;
```

I copied the view name with @ and replace them by "

```
DROP VIEW "your_view_name";
```